# Tool for visualizing OpenSCENARIO using an NDS map

Tags: xml, maps, openscenario, navigation-data-standard, xosc

I'm working on an OpenSCENARIO generator, and the scenarios I'm generating use NDS (Navigation Data Standard) maps.

```xml
 <RoadNetwork>

        <LogicFile filepath="map-name/ROOT.NDS" />

        <UsedArea>

            <Position>

                <GeoPosition latitudeDeg="47.9131" longitudeDeg="11.1923" />

            </Position>


            <Position>

                <GeoPosition latitudeDeg="47.9131" longitudeDeg="11.1923" />

            </Position>

        </UsedArea>

    </RoadNetwork>
```

I'm looking for a tool that I can use to visualize the output of my work.

I know there is the popular [esmini](https://github.com/esmini/esmini) tool, my problem is that it only supports roads in OpenDrive format (.xodr) while I'm using the NDS format as it can be seen in the logic file tag.

Comment: I remember reading into the esmini issues that there is no current plan to support NDS. Maybe you can try with Carla